# Keep getting the same error when I try to plot this data, what could be the issue?

Tags: r

Here is the code and the error message I keep getting

```
# Plot volume vs. basal area
plot(tree_dat$ba, tree_dat$vol, xlab= "Basal Area (ft^2)", ylab = "Volume (Intl. 1/4-in BF)")

Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Comment: I'm guessing, as I can't see your data, but `tree_dat$vol` probably doesn't exist, or if it does, is all `NA`. Type `tree_dat$vol` at the command line and see what you get.

Comment: The code itself looks fine to me. You may want to check your data.